# Getting error foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'xyz' because 'xyz' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, episerver

I have created a Model based on an EpiServer LinkItemCollection:

```
namespace ProjectX.Site.Models.Blocks
{
    [SiteContentType(
        GUID = "b9978bf2-f3da-4164-8fa2-3694c2ce0377", 
        AvailableInEditMode = false)]
    [SiteImageUrl]
    public class CustomTopNavigationItemtBlock : SiteBlockData
    {

        [CultureSpecific]
        [MinItemCount(0)]
        [MaxItemCount(2)]
        [Display(Order = 10)]
        public virtual LinkItemCollection CustomTopNavigationLinks { get; set; }

        public override int WordCount
        {
            get => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            set => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to create a shared view for it:

```
@model CustomTopNavigationItemtBlock

@if (Model != null)
{
    @foreach (var linkItem in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <a class=""
               href="@Url.PageUrl(linkItem.Href)"
               target="@linkItem.Target"
               title="@linkItem.Title"
               tabindex="1"
               data-toggle=""
               role="button">
                @linkItem.Text
            </a>
        </li>
    }
}
```

Unfortunatley I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `foreach (var linkItem in Model.CustomTopNavigationLinks)`

Comment: `CustomTopNavigationItemtBlock` does not implement `IEnumerable` hence the error. What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: Jonathan Barclays suggestion worked. But I don't understand why?

Comment: @BrokenCode Because `Model` is a `CustomTopNavigationItemtBlock`. It is not a collection and therefore cannot be iterated over. It does, however, have a property `CustomTopNavigationLinks` of type `LinkItemCollection` which is what you are trying to iterate.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, I get it now! Please feel free to provide this as the answer so I may give you kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are attempting to iterate over `Model`:

```
foreach (var linkItem in Model)
```

However, `Model` is of type `CustomTopNavigationItemtBlock`, which cannot be iterated using `foreach`, as it does not implement `IEnumerable`.

It seems that you are trying to loop over the `CustomTopNavigationLinks` property, which can be done like this:

```
foreach (var linkItem in Model.CustomTopNavigationLinks)
```